# Validating a credit card number using Luhn's algorithm

Tags: validation, bash, shell, checksum

I implemented [Luhn's algorithm explained on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) to validate a credit card number, in Bash.

Does this code follow good practices?

```
#!/bin/bash
getchecknumber(){ # get the last digit of the cc number
    str=$1
    checknum=$(echo ${str: -1})
}
getrest(){ # get the rest of the numbers in the sequence
    str=$(echo ${str%?})
}
doubleeveryother(){ # double every other number
    # split characters into an array
    arr=()
    i=0
    while [ "$i" -lt "${#str}" ]; do
        arr+=(${str:$i:1})
        i=$((i+1))
    done
    for ((i=1; i<=15; i++))
    do  {
        char=$(echo "$i-1" | bc)
        double=$(echo "${arr[$char]} * 2" | bc)
        if [ $(($i%2)) -eq 0 ] ; then foo=bar; else arr[$char]=$double #replace the number in the array
        fi
    }
    done
    echo -e
}
adddigitsum() { #split a two digit number into two numbers and add them
    for ((a=0; a<=14; a++))
    do {

        NUMSPLIT=()
        number=$(echo ${arr[$a]})
        if [[ ${#number} == 2 ]] ; then
            i=0
            while [[ "$i" -lt ${#number} ]]; do
                NUMSPLIT+=(${number:$i:1})
                i=$((i+1))
                done
            num=$((${NUMSPLIT[0]} + ${NUMSPLIT[1]}))
            addeddigit=$( echo $num | bc )
            arr[$a]=$addeddigit # replace the number in the array
        fi
    }
    done
}
addall(){ #add all the digits
    sum=$( IFS="+"; bc <<< "${arr[*]}" )
}
multiply(){ #multiply by 9
    result=$( echo "$sum * 9" | bc )
}
validate(){ #see if the last number of 'result' is equal to the checknum
    resultchecknum=$(echo ${result: -1})
    if [[ $resultchecknum == $checknum ]] ; then echo "CC Number is valid!" ; else echo "CC Number is not valid."
    fi
}
echo "$1 "
getchecknumber $1
getrest
doubleeveryother
adddigitsum
addall
multiply
validate
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if [ $(($i%2)) -eq 0 ] ; then foo=bar; else arr[$char]=$double
```

Then `foo=bar`? In any case, an alternative way of writing this is something like (borrowing your final `if` statement):

```
[[ $resultchecknum == $checknum ]] && echo "CC Number is valid!" \
                                    || echo "CC Number is not valid."
```

Also, you have a mix of `echo "..." | bc` and `bc <<< "..."`, I suggest keeping to the latter as it simpler to write.

A similar alternative to if-then-else is using `&&`:

```
[ ! $(($i%2)) -eq 0 ] && arr[$char]=$double
```

Answer (score 3):

> Does this code follow good practices?

It has some violations.

#### Avoid sub-shells when you don't need one

Instead of this:

```
str=$1
checknum=$(echo ${str: -1})
```

You can use parameter expansion (`${...}`) directly without a sub-shell:

> ```
> str=$1
> checknum=${str: -1}
> ```

The same goes for the similar use in the `getrest` function.

#### Arithmetic operations

Instead of this:

> ```
> while [ "$i" -lt "${#str}" ]; do
>     arr+=(${str:$i:1})
>     i=$((i+1))
> done
> ```

It's better to use `((...))` for arithmetic operations, like this:

```
while (( i < ${#str} )); do
    arr+=(${str:$i:1})
    ((++i))
done
```

#### Empty `then` in `if` statements

I see you added a dummy assignment `foo=bar` in this `if` statement because the `then` clause cannot be empty:

> ```
> if [ $(($i%2)) -eq 0 ] ; then foo=bar; else arr[$char]=$double; fi
> ```

In such situation, it's better to negate the condition:

```
if ! [ $(($i%2)) -eq 0 ] ; then arr[$char]=$double; fi
```

#### Odd groupings

The grouping with `{...}` is strange and unnecessary here:

> ```
> while condition
> do {
>     # ...
> }
> done
> ```

Unless you need the `{...}` for something, then it's better to write simpler:

```
while condition
do
    # ...
done
```

#### Avoid `echo -e`

The various flags of `echo` are not portable.
Avoid them when possible.

The command `echo -e` without other arguments is exactly the same as `echo`. So just write `echo` and that's it.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Janos' points (which are all very good points) it should be noted that variables in Bash are untyped (in other words - a string that is made up of numerics can be used in arithmetic). So the conversion from string to array is unnecessary.

With that in mind (and because I found this question whilst looking for a Bash implementation of the Luhn check) I thought I'd provide what I ended up using:

```
#!/bin/bash

pan=$1
panlen=${#pan}

for i in $(seq $((panlen - 1)) -1 0); do
  digit=${pan:$i:1}
  if [ $(((panlen-i) % 2)) -eq 0 ]; then
     #even
     ((digit*=2))
     [ ${#digit} -eq 2 ] && digit=$((${digit:0:1}+${digit:1:1}))
  fi
  ((sum+=digit))
done

[ $((sum % 10)) -eq 0 ] || exit 1
```

This script takes a single parameter (the PAN) and exits with `1` if the PAN is invalid. For example, if we place this script in a file called `isLUHNValid.sh` we can run it with a valid PAN like:

```
./isLUHNValid.sh 4388576018410707 && echo 'Valid PAN' || echo 'Invalid PAN'
```

which will echo 'Valid PAN'.

And with an invalid PAN:

```
./isLUHNValid.sh 4388576018410708 && echo 'Valid PAN' || echo 'Invalid PAN'
```

it will echo 'Invalid PAN'.

Comment: Good point about untyped variables, and welcome to Code Review. Btw if you post your version up for review, I'll have a few comments on it ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I'd actually love feedback. Should I make a new post? Being new here I'm not really sure of the shoulds and should nots. If I make a new post - do I just say "Here's a script I wrote. Looking for feedback"?

Comment: Something like that, but do read the [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [on-topic](/help/on-topic) pages first

Comment: Thanks again Janos. I've posted my version here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/129649/bash-script-to-perform-luhn-check